# Azure AD B2C - KMSI - Remeber me functionality on site that does not force login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Scenario:
I am working on a corporate site, on which you may log in, but it is not a forced requirement.
We have enabled the KeepMeSignedIn / Remember me functionality on the aadb2c login page, but i cannot seem to figure out how to notify my website, if a user has selected to KMSI.

My Question:
How can I signal back to my website, if the user has chosen to use the KMSI / Remember Me functionality on AADB2C.
I can't seem to find any information solving this challenge and I would very much appreciate your help and input.

Kr Ole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the KMSI Claim Resolver to detect if the user selected KMSI check box and issue the claim into the token.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#context